# howler.js update volume of a sound

Tags: javascript, audio, howler.js

I am working with

> howler.js 2.0

but cant seem to get a simple example of updating the volume working. Here some a sample code:

```
window.sound = new Howl({
 src:'http://example.com/assets/audio/background.mp3',
  loop: true,
  volume: 0.15
});

window.updateVolume = function(value) {
  alert('before update volume:', window.sound.volume());
  sound.volume = value;
  alert('after update volume:', window.sound.volume());
}
```

I have tried both using `volume() function` and just `volume` property. None seem to work.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/umx2bdm8/

What am I missing? Also, I noticed that if you click `play` multiple times, multiple instances of the same sound start playing. I dont want that and hitting `play` on a particular `howl` instance should always work with that instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look at [howler.js 2.0’s docs for `volume`](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/tree/2.0#volumevolume-id), it shows that `volume` is a function, not an assignable property, and that you need to pass in the new volume as an argument to set the volume. So you need to do `sound.volume(value)` instead of `sound.volume = value`.

```js
sound = new Howl({
  src: 'http://www.hochmuth.com/mp3/Tchaikovsky_Rococo_Var_orch.mp3',
  loop: true,
  volume: 0.5
});

updateVolume = function(value) {
  console.log('before update volume:', sound.volume());
  sound.volume(value);
  console.log('after update volume:', sound.volume());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/howler/2.0.0-beta13/howler.min.js"></script>


<button onclick="sound.play()">
  Play
</button>
<button onclick="updateVolume(0.15)">
  Change volume to 0.15
</button>
```

(I switched the volume values above for demo purposes, so listeners don’t have to worry whether the music will suddenly deafen them when they click the button.)

Comment: Do you also know why multiple instances of the sound play if you hit `play` several times?

Comment: No, I don’t know why – [the docs for `play`](https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/tree/2.0#playspriteid) don’t mention that that is supposed to happen. But I know that you can fix it by changing the HTML to `onclick="sound.stop(); sound.play()"`.